# consolidate file choose and upload in one line in angularJs only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, I choose the file and upload using 2 different buttons as follows:

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile" />
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
```

Is it possible to choose the file and upload in 1 single button?

I tried the following but did not work.

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile" onchange="uploadFile()" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ng-file-select like this:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="fname" ng-file-select="uploadFile($files)">
```

Inside your controller, you'll get object:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function($files) {
    var file = $files[0];
    console.log(file);
}
```

More details:
http://blog.gitbd.org/file-upload-by-angular-and-php/

Comment: I think that nuget package for angular-file-upload are broken .. so the https cdngs links for angular-file_upload*.js worked for me. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile" onChange="uploadFile()" />
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script>

function uploadFile(){
     alert("function accessed");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" file-model="myFile" onChange="uploadFile()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I tagged my question, I was looking for only Angularjs answer.